# How to abort a thread that runs unmanaged code

Tags: c#, multithreading, unmanaged

I am developing a multi-threaded application.

one of my threads runs unmanaged code, and when the unmanaged code rise an exception, the thread.Abort() dose not do any action. and running will stop in the thrad.Abort() line.

How can I abort the thread that runs an unmanaged code in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Assuming that your thread is running unmanaged code and managed code I propouse that you have a flag and the thread in the managed code Abort its self.

Something like this:

```
 private Thread thread1 = null;
 private bool thread1Abort = false;

 private void KillAllThreads() {
        if (thread1 != null && thread1 .IsAlive)
            thread1Abort = true;
 }
 private void function1() {
    try {
            if (mDocumentGroupThreadAbort) {
                mDocumentGroupThreadAbort = false;
                //Is you want to restart the thread may be a problem using abort. Thread will raise an error because the abort is not concluded.
                //mDocumentGroupThread.Abort();
                return;
            }
            //function with unmanaged code...
    } catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException) {
            ....
    } finally {
            ...
    }
}
static void Main(){
    this.thread1 = new Thread(() => {
            function1();
        });
    this.thread1.Start();
    Console.Readline();
}
```

PS: I don't know if it is a bad solutions but it worked for me